# Modifying OpenLDAP configuration using cn=config

Tags: openldap

I am really new to OpenLDAP. I am trying to view all the settings in cn=config and attempt to change the value of olcSizeLimit (http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html#cn=config)

I try the following command (as root in the server terminal) but it prompts that it cannot find anything

> root@admin:/home/administrator# ldapsearch -D "cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" -b "cn=config" -W    >Enter LDAP Password:
>
> extended LDIF
>
> LDAPv3
>   base  with scope subtree
>
> filter: (objectclass=*)
>
> requesting: ALL
>
> search result
>
> search: 2
>
> result: 32 No such object
>
> numResponses: 1

cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com is the default administrator setup during OpenLDAP installation and is the olcRootDN

Any help? Btw I am using OpenLDAP 2.4 install on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com` is the administrator for your main database, but probably not for the OLC. By default, connecting as the root user over `ldapi://` allows you to manage the configuration.

As root: `ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -b cn=config`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I tried the command and it works.So even though cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com is the olcRootDN, it doesn't mean that it can edit the cn=config file? Anyways, what is ldapi://?

Comment: @caveman: `cn=config` is a separate database with a separate admin account. `ldapi://` is a method to connect directly to the server bypassing authentication. It only works on the host running the LDAP server as it uses [Unix domain sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) and is usually limited to the `root` user (`uid=0,gid=0`).